# How can I make an HTML/NodeJS form go to another form based on a response, sort of like Google Form's "Go to section based on answer?"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

So I have a NodeJS site and on the home page is a form containing some radio buttons. When the user clicks "Submit," I would like for the user to be redirected to another page based on the answer. This I have figured out (The buttons have an `onclick` attribute that changes the `action` attribute of the form element). However, **I need to keep the data from the original form, so that after the user has "chosen their path," I know what path the took and the answers they made along it.** Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could persist the client's state in a session. If you're using express, one alternative could be [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session). The way it works is that it assigns a unique identifier to the user in the form of a cookie and saves the data somewhere (memory, database, a file, etc. depending on which you choose). Then when the client makes another request, the server gets that data back with the identifier from the cookie.

Comment: @cubrr Thank you so much! I'm not using express, but cookies were a great idea! Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Sure thing! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could persist the client's state in a session. If you're using express, one alternative could be [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session). The way it works is that it assigns a unique identifier to the user in the form of a cookie and saves the data somewhere (memory, database, a file, etc. depending on which you choose). Then when the client makes another request, the server gets that data back with the identifier from the cookie.